# Can an Excel column or graph show a sorted version of a linked column?

Tags: excel

Let's say I have an alphabetical list of student names and (numeric) grades in an Excel worksheet. In a separate worksheet, I would like to view the grades sorted by decreasing order. That's all.

To be clear: I do know how to sort a range of cells in place. But if I create a range of references to another range and sort that manually, the references are adjusted and I'm still looking at the unsorted column. Linking to a column in another worksheet is a trivial matter, but although Excel has the concept of "array functions", it seems to have no functions for mapping a range of cells to its sorted version (or for any kind of non-interactive sorting, really).

My immediate goal is to make a bar graph with the numbers in descending order, so if there is a way to generate such a graph from an unsorted range, I'd like to hear about it too. But I can think of several use cases where multiple orders for the same range of cells would be useful:

1. I need a column with the difference between each number and the
   next larger number (easy when the numbers are sorted), but my main worksheet is sorted alphabetically by
   name.
2. I have data on one worksheet alphabetized by client name, and want
   another sheet with (some of) the same data sorted by city, or by
   date. Sorting and re-sorting interactively is not an option unless I want exactly 
   the  same layout.
3. My worksheet is arranged chronologically and I want an alphabetized version of it.

I've googled around and the answers range from "why would you want to do such a thing" (for a different use case) to VBA approaches that would paste in a sorted copy of the range. That's what I'm doing for now, minus the automation: Selecting the data, pasting the *values* (using Paste Special), and ordering the copied version. If the original data changes, I have to do it over.

Can multiple orderings really be so rarely needed that they are not supported, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I was just thinking about this today except I was thinking about this in SQL.  SQL really should have a way to do multiple orderings too like an ORDER BY ORDERING SETS or something.  Maybe one way to do what you want is to add columns with integers that sort the data the way you want and setup another table to do a VLOOKUP on those integers.

Comment: But in SQL you can at least specify an ORDER BY clause with each SELECT, and even create views with different orders. If Excel could do any of that, I wouldn't be asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this all the time. Basically, you translate the order you want (either ascending/descending) into the row index in the unsorted list, then use index to look that value up for you.

```
=INDEX(<insert range here>, MATCH(SMALL(COUNTIF(<insert range here>, "<"&<insert range here>), ROW(1:1)), COUNTIF(<insert range here>, "<"&<insert range here>), 0))
```

[Sorted Array Example.xlsx](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14917/Sorted%20Array%20Example.xlsx)

[Source](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/27/sorting-text-cells-using-array-formula/)

Comment: Thanks for the formula and the sample! Wow, that's complicated. Your solution takes care of my problem, which is just to graph the numbers. But your formula also reorders the names next to the numbers, and that has a bug: If two names have the same grade, the sorted list will just contain one of the names twice. Do you see a way to fix this? (Other than manually entering a rank column..)

Answer (score 1):

Have you Rank function and combining with vlookup. Sorry I can't link files. But let's say you have the data in Range("A1:C5"):

```
Rank Name Score
2    Scott 45
1    Mark  74
3    Chris 39
4    Brian 18
```

Formula for rank column (cell A1) = =rank(C2,$C$2:$C$5,0)

Then in Range("E1:G5"):

```
Rank   Name    Score
1      Mark    74
2      Scott   45
3      Chris   39
4      Brian   18
```

where:

```
Rank column is hardcoded
Name column (F2) is  =VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$C$5,2,FALSE)
Score column (G2) is =VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE)
```